# Using a StaticResource inside a ListBox.ItemContainerStyle throws exception

Tags: wpf

The following code throws the exception "System.NullReferenceException was unhandled
  Message=Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
  Source=Wizbang":

```
<ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
        <Style.Resources>
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="SCB" Color="Orange" />
        </Style.Resources>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True" >
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource SCB}" />
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Orange" />
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
```

However, if I remove the StaticResource reference in the first Trigger's Setter, and replace it with string value, such as, "Orange", like in the second Trigger, everything works fine.

I cannot figure out why.  I use StaticResources similarly in Triggers elsewhere, but it seems that since this is a ListBox.ItemContainerStyle, something works differently.

Comment: I'm not sure if it would work, or if it's the right thing to do, but try using DynamicResource instead of StaticResource. Maybe there's a chance that the SolidColorBrush is still not loaded when the triggers' initialization is done.

Comment: Are you sure above code is your real issue? It works fine in a demo project and what puzzles me is the error message "Source=Wizbang". There is no Wizbang object in your xaml code ...

Comment: Wizbang is my project name.  As I describe in the post, taking away the reference to the StaticResource allows the code to compile and run.  It has something to do with using a StaticResource on a Trigger in a ListBox.ItemContainerStyle.

Comment: @Orchestrator: Making it a DynamicResource fixed the problem.  I thought that I had tried that!  If you can post your reply as an answer, perhaps with a link or further description as to why the Resource is not initialized before the Trigger tries to reference it, I can give you credit for the answer. Fwiw, I originally tried putting the resource in a higher level resource directory, and the StaticResource reference was failing;  putting the resource in the Style.Resources was an attempt to bring the Resource "closer".